Why do the .ogg and .oga formats play on macOS but not on mobile iOS devices?
I have audio files with .ogg and .oga formats. They work on all devices(except iOS mobile and tablet). Are not they supported in the browser for iOS?
I use wavesurfer.js library and pass the url to the WavesurferPlayer com
      <div
        className="audioMessage__content"
        style={{
          background: `linear-gradient(to right, rgba(51, 97, 255, 0.2) ${progress}%, white ${progress}%)`,
        }}
      >
        <button className="audioMessage__btn" onClick={onPlayPause}>
          {isPlaying ? <AudioPauseIcon /> : <AudioPlayIcon className="audioMessage__playIcon" />}
        </button>

        <div className="audioMessage__waveWrapper">
          <WavesurferPlayer
            height={18}
            width="100%"
            waveColor="#C3CAD9"
            progressColor="#3361FF"
            url={audioUrl}
            onReady={onReady}
            onPlay={() => setIsPlaying(true)}
            onPause={() => setIsPlaying(false)}
            barAlign="bottom"
            barWidth={3}
            barGap={2}
            barRadius={4}
          />
          <div className="audioMessage__currentTime">{formatTime(currentTime)}</div>
        </div>
      </div>

